"error": "rule not matched for function \"data/v1/endpoint in mongoDB Data api


{
    "error": "rule not matched for function \"data/v1/insertOne\"",
    "error_code": "FunctionExecutionError",
    "link": "https://services.cloud.mongodb.com/groups/63b5682c9dc61178d7dbb789/apps/6603b655efeb26a20b98d2e6/logs?co_id=660d3195f283bb3b97a1236b"
}



I have reviewed the MongoDB Realm documentation and verified my implementation, but I'm unable to identify the root cause of this issue. The error seems to suggest that a rule is not being matched for the insertOne function.
Could someone provide insights into what might be causing this error and how I can troubleshoot it further? Additionally, if anyone has encountered similar issues or has experience with MongoDB Data API, any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

i have use mongodb data api. that's work without write logic use only endpoints
that is documentaion https://www.w3schools.com/mongodb/mongodb_data_api.php

Then show the request / curl command you used to create the document. Is your API key correct? Is your data in the correct format?

yes, i have add all credential is perfect but after api hit body data not capture but if any other credential ( api key, content-type, endpoint ) add wrong so show other error. and if empty body or add data in body so showing uper error.
{
"dataSource": "Darshand",
"database": "test",
"collection": "user",
"document": {
"name": "John Sample",
"age": 42
}
}
that my data add in body

resolve error : We guys used to add values to the database built in the old Atlas cluster. After we created a new database and collection, it started running.And we guys did it from a new account,

Please verify your database settings or version when you initiated the process. I encountered the same error with my older database, but the issue was resolved when I created a new one. Hence, I suggest checking the configuration or trying with a new database.
